# How to get model from server and display on view?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have already get the collection from server and displayed on view. Now I want to get details of single item when i pass Id to server. First I am getting collection and display in a grid. Now If someone clicks on gridview row then I passes id in url. I want to get Model by passing this Id. What I do to get Model. I am getting Error -  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

************ Model start ************************

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone'
], function ($, _, Backbone) {
    var Order = Backbone.Model.extend({
        idAttribute: "ID",
    });
    return Order;
});
```

************* Model End **************************

*************** View Start ***********************

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'text!templates/orderDetails.html',
  'collections/OrderCollection',
  'collections/ItemCollection',
  'models/Orders',
], function ($, _, Backbone, orderDetails, OrderCollection, ItemCollection,Orders) {

    var ProfileView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("#content"),
        render: function (Id) {
            this.Id = Id;
            var self = this;
            this.order = new Orders();
            this.order.fetch({
                url: 'GetOrderDetails',
                data: JSON.stringify({ orderId: window.Id }),
                success: function () {
                    self.renderList();
                },
                error: function (a, b, c) {
                    alert(a);
                }
            });

        },
        renderList: function () {

            var compiledTemplate = _.template(orderDetails, { Details: this.order, Items: this.order.Items });
            this.$el.html(compiledTemplate);

        }
    });

    return ProfileView;
});
```

*************** View End ************************

Can someone help me regarding this issue.

Thanks & Regards

shwetamber

Comment: I think you need to clean up your code a little.  I'm having a bit of hard time to read this.  Statement like this.order = new Orders() are confusing. Are you creating new Order model or Orders Collection. There is a window.ID in there that comes out of nowhere. In you're render function you're fetching stuff from the server, while you should be only updating the view in it in my opinion.  Since backbone itself is pretty open to interpretations on how you should use it I would really suggest you use Marionette with it.  It will give you a decent structure and make handling nested views easier.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your main problem is in the `renderList` function. Now I don't know what your model looks like, so maybe it'll be helpful to add that in your description.  But the main problem is how you're attaching your model to the template.  You can't just throw the model class into the template, you have to grab the attributes of the model.  So maybe you're looking for this:

```
renderList: function () {

    var compiledTemplate = _.template(orderDetails, { Details: this.order.attributes, Items: this.order.get('Items') });
    this.$el.html(compiledTemplate);

}
```